# try-catch in kotlin coroutine with withContext method

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I found some documentation arguing about exception handling in Kotlin's coroutines with `launch` and `async`. But I could not found the solution dealing with the `withContext`.

suppose I have a coroutine like:

```kotlin
fun bar(path: String) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val foo = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
             foo(path)
        }
    }
}

fun foo(path: String) {
    // do something...
    val media = MediaMetadataRetriever()
    media.setDataSource(path)  // may throw IllegalArgumentException according to API's doc
    return media.frameAtTime
}
```

`viewModelScope` is imported from the `lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx`'s implementation using a `SupervisorJob`.

Where should I put a try-catch block to deal with the IOException here?

Comment: From the design lead of Kotlin: https://medium.com/@elizarov/kotlin-and-exceptions-8062f589d07 TLDR: Don't throw exceptions unless they're runtime exceptions (caused by programmer error). Use a result wrapper or return null for errors. Wrap exceptions from Java libraries in one of the above using your own helper function when the standard lib doesn't provide it. `try-catch` in Kotlin is a code smell, unless it is in one of these helper functions.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I agree with you. But my problem is that the foo function here uses an API as it throws exception according to documentation. I edited my code here.

Comment: `withContext` should return a value. You should catch exception around your API call and make `foo()` return failure/success object. Otherwise exception will be propagated as `withContext` result and you can catch it there. If you don't it's gonna be rethrown again and default exception handler of `launch` will throw it as uncaught exception & your app will crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**try-catch** in Kotlin coroutines feels a little clumsy, but I think it's partially because the designers of Kotlin don't think you should be using it in the first place. When something is a checked exception (caused by something outside the programmer's control), their recommendation is to wrap it or return null. For example:

```
fun foo(path: String): Bitmap? {
    // do something...
    val media = MediaMetadataRetriever()
    try {
        media.setDataSource(path)
    catch (e: IOException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to set media data source", e)
        return null
    }
    return media.frameAtTime
}

fun bar(path: String) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val foo = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
             foo(path)
        }
        if (foo == null) {
            // show error to user or something
        } else {
           // do something with smart-cast non-null foo Bitmap
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, for a blocking function like `foo` that you will never call from the main thread, I suggest making it a `suspend` function and moving the `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` into the function so it is self-contained and you can freely call it from any coroutine.